# How to access elements inside jQuery tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to access some elements inside the tab upon user clicking on tab.

```
$('.myTabs').tabs({
    activate: function(event,ui){
        console.log("Give me some tab contents here...");
    }
});
```

PS: I can't use ID to go directly to my tab because the serverside renders multiple tabs with varying Id's.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which elements exactly do you want to reference in the tab?

Comment: Let's just say a few textboxes.

Comment: I think you can use the `ui` parameter's `newPanel` property.

Comment: I have a fiddle almost done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ui` parameter's `newPanel` property:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function(event,ui) {
        console.log(ui.newPanel.find('p').text());
    }
});
```

Note: The `ui.newPanel` property is a jQuery object.

For more information see the [jQuery UI Tabs documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate).

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uv2Fg/1/)

Comment: @RealityDysfunction - I updated the code to remove the unnecessary call to `$()`. It turns out the `ui.newPanel` value is a jQuery object, not a DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/RNvwv/6/**

```
$('.myTabs').tabs({
    activate: function(event,ui){
        //alert(ui.newTab.index());
        //console.log(ui);
        //console.log(ui.newPanel.selector);
        //Here is how to reference a text value in the tab you are clicking on...
        alert($(ui.newPanel.selector+' [name^="myField"]').val());
    }
});
```

Obviously you could change the selector for your text fields to be on the specific ID or something else.  I went with name that starts with "myField" so that when you go to tab 2 it finds `"myField2"` and when you go back to tab 1 it finds `"myField1"`.